# Rename a schema that contains an extension used by another schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgis, pg-dump

How can you rename a schema containing an extension without breaking tables in other schemas that rely on this extension (PostGIS)?

I'm trying to temporarily rename a schema "dest" to "public" in order to save a backup with the name "dest. In order to do this:

1. Rename `public` to `public_old`
2. Rename `dest` to `public`
3. `pg_dump ...`

However, step 1 causes the `geometry` type in `public` to become `public_old.geometry`:

```
\d dest.geo_choice
                                       Table "dest.geo_choice"
           Column           |   Type   |                          Modifiers
----------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 geom                       | geometry |

ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO public_old;

                                             Table "dest.geo_choice"
           Column           |        Type         |                          Modifiers
----------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 geom                       | public_old.geometry |


select GeometryType(geom) from dest.geo_choice;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I avoid this breakage so we can carry out `pg_dump`?

Comment: How difficult is it to reinstall the extension in the new public schema?

Comment: Uninstall it first from the old one and then reinstall it? I guess that would work as a workaround.

Comment: Actually no. When you uninstall it, you'd lose all extension-specific data in both schemas.